# Defining a screen in PyGame and not show it

Tags: python, pygame

I'm writing a script on PyGame that should create an image and save it, not show it. The process of generating and saving is perfect, but when I use `myscreen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])`, it causes a windows to be open, on the size I'm defining. Once I'm not giving any `pygame.display.flip()` the window just blinks, appear and dissapear.

I would like to know if there is a way to initialize a screen in PyGame and not show it, so, I could create my image and just save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `display` to create it.  You can just construct a [`Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) and use it in conjunction with [`image.save()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save) to save it, or use something like [`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to create an image without using PyGame at all.

Comment: Thank you @Silas Ray! The `Surface` solution was perfect!